# What is the difference between a variable and a mixin in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have been doing some googling and I currently understand the difference being that a variable stores a single line of information whereas, a mixin stores multiple lines of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

> Variables begin with dollar signs, and are set like CSS properties.
>   You can then refer to them in properties:

```
$width: 5em;

#main {
  width: $width; // width is set as 5em
}
```

> On the other hand, Mixins allow you to define styles that can be re-used throughout the stylesheet

```
@mixin large-text { // defining mixing
  font: {
    family: Arial;
    size: 20px;
    weight: bold;
  }
  color: #ff0000;
}

.page-title { // applying mixin
  @include large-text;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The above code is compiled to:

```
.page-title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff0000;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know c++ or any other programming language, then you can refer sass variable as global variable of c or c++, and sass mixin as function of c or c++ .

Mixin do some kind of styling which can be used again again in your whole styling and same you can use variable as much as you can.

Comment: Functions and Mixins are different. One returns value while the other is used like a macro to substitute.

Comment: I know they are different, but am just trying to help him out to understand about the basic idea. We can relate them, as mixins & functions both took arguments and parameters. and both do some kind of styling and functionality respectively.