# why use $ sign in CSS property values?

Tags: css

I've come across this code and can't find documentation of its use anywhere:

```
#navbar {
    color: $white;
    }
```

and 'background: $black;'

Why use '$' sign?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841041/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-a-mixin-in-sass/43841207#43841207 and http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: This is not CSS code. This is a CSS pre-processor code. [read more](https://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus)

Comment: variable, color code maybe assigned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a variable and a mixin in sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841041/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-a-mixin-in-sass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are variables that are interpreted and replaced via a CSS preprocessor such as SASS, saving you potential time and effort say when changing a base colour or style. For more information, check out: http://sass-lang.com/

**Example**

```css
$base_width: 5em;
$base_colour: #FFFFFF;

#main {
  width: $base_width; // width is set as 5em
}
#secondary_div{
  width: $base_width;
  background: $base_color;
}
```

Comment: he use color no width. he use white no number.

Comment: @ehsan Doesn't make a difference - the concept is variables not the values they hold. But see the updated example anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Can't do that in CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp link to all the legal ways you can specify colors in css.